# Replacing multiple CREATE VIEW with just one SELECT statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED VIEW `day0` AS 
SELECT `c`.`customerId` AS `CustomerID`,SUM(`t`.`orderTotal`) AS `Day0`,
       `t`.`dateOfSale` AS `DateOfSale`,`c`.`initialDateOfSale` AS `InitialDateOfSale`     
FROM `customer` `c` LEFT JOIN
     `transaction` `t`
      on `t`.`customerId` = `c`.`customerId`
where `t`.`status` = 2 and `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 1 day) 
GROUP BY `c`.`customerId';

CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED VIEW `day30` AS 
SELECT `c`.`customerId` AS `CustomerID`,SUM(`t`.`orderTotal`) AS `Day30`,
       `t`.`dateOfSale` AS `DateOfSale`,`c`.`initialDateOfSale` AS `InitialDateOfSale` 
FROM `customer` `c` LEFT JOIN
     `transaction` `t`
     on `t`.`customerId` = `c`.`customerId`
where `t`.`status` = 2 and `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 30 day) 
GROUP BY `c`.`customerId`;

CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED VIEW `day60` AS 
SELECT `c`.`customerId` AS `CustomerID`,SUM(`t`.`orderTotal`) AS `Day60`,
       `t`.`dateOfSale` AS `DateOfSale`,`c`.`initialDateOfSale` AS `InitialDateOfSale`
FROM `customer` `c` LEFT JOIN
     `transaction` `t`
     on `t`.`customerId` = `c`.`customerId`
where `t`.`status` = 2 and `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 60 day) 
GROUP BY `c`.`customerId`;

SELECT day0.customerid,day0.day0, day30.day30, day60.day60, 
FROM day0, day30, day60,
WHERE day0.customerid=day0.customerid and day0.customerid=day30.customerid and
      day0.customerid=day60.customerid
```

Is there anyway to replace multiple CREATE VIEW statements with just one SELECT without creating new views/tables inside the database? Besides this the end user would not have the CREATE VIEW privilege.

Thank you,

Oikif

Comment: It would help if you formatted the code.  As a hint:  things look like code when you precede them with at least four spaces on each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with one simpler query:

```
SELECT c.`customerId` AS `CustomerID` ,
       SUM(case when `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 1 day)
                then `t`.`orderTotal`
                else 0
           end) AS `Day0`,
       SUM(case when `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 60 day)
                then `t`.`orderTotal`
                else 0
           end) AS `Day60`,
       SUM(case when `t`.`dateOfSale` <= DATE_ADD(`c`.`initialDateOfSale`, interval 90 day)
                then `t`.`orderTotal`
                else 0
           end) AS `Day90`,
       `t`.`dateOfSale` AS `DateOfSale`, `c`.`initialDateOfSale` AS `InitialDateOfSale`
FROM `customer` `c` LEFT JOIN
     `transaction` `t`
     on `t`.`customerId` = `c`.`customerId`
where `t`.`status` = 2
GROUP BY `c`.`customerId`;
```

You can create a view around this query.

Comment: Great! Thank you Gordon. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A view in mySQL is just basically a table representing a query. If you, for example, were doing something simple like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 'myView' AS SELECT matNumber, SUM(inv) FROM inventory;
SELECT matNumber, totalInventory FROM myView;
```

You could replace it by using subqueries:

```
SELECT new_inventory.matNumber, 
       new_inventory.totalInventory 
FROM ( SELECT matNumber, sum(inv) FROM inventory ) new_inventory;
```

Just remember each derived table needs an alias. While this isn't a solution to your exact problem, it should provide you the general direction.